# Why does my Lambda function send an SQS message twice with one call?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, es6-promise, amazon-sqs

I need to only deliver a message to a standard (not FIFO, but is not related to the question) SQS queue, *once* with *one* call.

However, the code below is sending 2 messages with 1 call.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
AWS.config.update({region: process.env.AWS_REGION})
const sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});

async function sendToSQSEvent(body,attributes=null){
    var m_body 
    if (attributes != null)
    {
            m_body = {
                body : body,
                attributes : attributes
                };
    }
    else{
        m_body = body;
    }
    m_body = JSON.stringify(m_body);
            
 var params = {
    //  DelaySeconds: 0,   <-- i try but only delay reception 
      MessageAttributes: {
        "Title": {
          DataType: "String",
          StringValue: "TIME_OUT"
        },
        "Author": {
          DataType: "String",
          StringValue: "LAMBDA_IN"
        },
      },
      MessageBody: m_body,
      QueueUrl: "https://my_url/sqs"
    };
    console.log('_________CALL_______________');
    var r = await sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
      } else {
        console.log("Success", data.MessageId ,data);
      }
    }).promise(console.log("_________in promise___________"));
   console.log("___end")
}

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
     await sendToSQSEvent(event)
};
```

Console output is:

```
START RequestId: RequestId Version: $LATEST
2021-10-11T06:23:52.992Z    RequestId   INFO    _________CALL_______________
2021-10-11T06:23:53.425Z    RequestId   INFO    _________in promise___________
2021-10-11T06:23:53.728Z    RequestId   INFO    Success ********-****-****-****-*********b4f {
  ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: '********-****-****-****-*********89d' },
  MD5OfMessageBody: '********************************8f',
  MD5OfMessageAttributes: '***********************1b0',
  MessageId: '********-****-****-****-*********b4f'
}
2021-10-11T06:23:53.786Z    RequestId   INFO    ___end
2021-10-11T06:23:53.807Z    RequestId   INFO    Success ********-****-****-****-*********665 {
  ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: '********-****-****-****-********835' },
  MD5OfMessageBody: '***********************28f',
  MD5OfMessageAttributes: '***********************1b0',
  MessageId: '********-****-****-****-*********665'
}
END RequestId: RequestId
```

What is the issue?

Comment: Is that your entire lambda? It shouldn't send 2

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary                                                                                                            
 1) yes i just format event of `exports.handler = async (event, context)` .                          
 2) It's not a solution I don't get anything one my SQS  and nothing one console.                                                              thanks you for trying to help me

Comment: Ah OK - can you please update the question with your full code so it is reproducible?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary done :) let me now if you find something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's sending a message twice as you're mixing *synchronous* [callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) (`function(err, data)`) with *asynchronous* [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (`await`, `async function sendToSQSEvent(...)`).

You can see this as CloudWatch is logging 2 `sqs.sendMessage(...)` responses.

I would recommend sticking with the latter.

---

This should be your SQS `sendMessage` logic, which returns a promise object for your handler.

```
return sqs.sendMessage(params).promise();
```

You can then check the response in your handler:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    try {
        var data = await sendToSQSEvent(event)
        console.log("Success", data.MessageId ,data);
    }
    catch (err){
        console.log("Error", err);
    }
};
```

This should be the final working result:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
AWS.config.update({
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION
})
const sqs = new AWS.SQS({
    apiVersion: '2012-11-05'
});

async function sendToSQSEvent(body, attributes = null) {
    var m_body
    if (attributes != null) {
        m_body = {
            body: body,
            attributes: attributes
        };
    } else {
        m_body = body;
    }
    m_body = JSON.stringify(m_body);

    var params = {
        MessageAttributes: {
            "Title": {
                DataType: "String",
                StringValue: "TIME_OUT"
            },
            "Author": {
                DataType: "String",
                StringValue: "LAMBDA_IN"
            },
        },
        MessageBody: m_body,
        QueueUrl: "https://my_url/sqs"
    };

    return sqs.sendMessage(params).promise();
}

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    try {
        var data = await sendToSQSEvent(event)
        console.log("Success", data.MessageId ,data);
    }
    catch (err){
        console.log("Error", err);
    }
};
```

Comment: Well done! It looks ok now, but I can't understand why?    JS problem ? thk you !!

Comment: @jchenaud Was updating the answer with an explanation :) - does that make sense? You're welcome!

Comment: Perfectly  !! thks

Comment: Nice and detailed. Thanks Author

Comment: @RoelofBriers more than welcome, have a good day :)